# /s/S in ANTLR parser rules

Tags: java, regex, escaping, antlr, antlr4

I want to write a parser rule to parse a valid `String`, my rule goes like this:

`STRING: '"' [\s\S]+ '"';`

But it gives me a warning saying `invalid escape sequence \s`. I tried other escape sequence like `\t`, `\n`... they are all fine.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? `\s\S` is not supported? What alternatives can I find for parse a valid `String`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your mistake is on the `'"'`, can you replace them to `"`? Also, note that whitespaces matters in regex.

Comment: Use `[\\s\\S]+` inside a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR doesn't use Regex, even if it looks like that sometimes. It doesn't know escaped entities like `\s` or `\w`. You should instead use:

```
STRING: '"' .*? '"';
```

This is a non-greedy scan of any char between double quotes. ANTLR4 is clever enough to exclude the finishing quote from the any-char match. An often used variation of that is:

```
STRING: '"' ~["]* '"';
```

I recommend to look at existing grammars to learn how to write rules, e.g. in this [Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaLexer.g4#L104). Also read the [ANTLR4 documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md) about lexer rules on Github.